# Mako templates: alphabetically order the list

Tags: pyramid, mako

I'm working with Python/Pyramid and Mako Templates, and it's all pretty new for me.

I have a list over different templates, now the list comes out in a random order but I want it alphabetically. 
Does anyone have any suggestions? 
Here is the code that gets the list:

```
<div class="panel-small">

    <h2>Choose template</h2>

    <div id="template_list">

    % if template_list and len(template_list) > 0:

        % for template in template_list:

            % if template['template']:

                <a href="#${template['type']}_${template['template_id']}" id="${template['template_id']}" class="template_link ${template['type']}">${template['name']}<br />

            % else:

                % if template['url'] is not None and template['url'].startswith('mailto'):

                    <a href="${template['url']}" class="external">${template['name']}</a><br />

                % else:

                    <a href="${template['url']}" class="external" target="_blank">${template['name']}</a><br />

                % endif

            % endif

        % endfor

    % else:

        No template.

    % endif

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort your "template_list" in python before it gets rendered in the template.

Comment: Probably can use `sorted` directly in template too.

Comment: I believe you can but I try to keep my template code as simple as possible.  I don't know if one way is faster than the other.